# Excel spreadsheet for ordinal logistic regression

Tags: logistic, excel

Does anyone know of an existing implementation of ordinal logistic regression in Excel?

Comment: does the following link help ? http://archives.math.utk.edu/ICTCM/VOL13/C013/paper.html

Comment: yeah... I was looking at that earlier... It's good tutorial on how to use solver.. but it's less specific when it comes to ins and outs of ordianl logistic regression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your goal is didactic; that you are trying to explain ordinal logistic to some group of people.  I have used Excel for this sort of thing when the topic is much simpler - e.g., crosstabs and chi-square - so that there is some intuition about the formulas.

I don't think that will be the case here.  Even if you could find (or create) an Excel spreadsheet that does this, I think the intermediate steps are so numerous that it will not be clear to any audience that could not follow a more usual explanation of ordinal logistic.

I would use some standard software and give different examples. I've written a talk doing this, using SAS, but it could be done using R or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to recommend Excel (which has shown itself to be unreliable for simpler problems than the one posed) when R has well worked-out packages for this.

Comment: Agree. But I need it in excel for demostration purpose. Excel is very transparent.. shows every estimation step.

Comment: Not a good idea to demonstrate an untrustworthy platform, in my humble opinion.  Plus you will limit yourself quit a bit in terms of features implemented.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I will be not demostrating the platform but the ordianl logistic regression concept. Transparent simple example in excel will do that very efficiently... I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Since you just need it for demonstration, how about using [Minitab](http://www.minitab.com/en-US/default.aspx)? It is similarly transparent.

[RExcel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RExcel) looks promising too.

Of course, both of these options are somewhat opaque because all of the software is proprietary, closed-source software. You could also try [R and Calc](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/R_and_Calc), which uses open-source software. (I know that's not what you meant by transparent.)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. When I say transparent. I mean something like excel which allows me to see every step of the calculation.

Comment: I don't need to see/know/understand source code of the platform I'm using...